# не выводится столбец с русским названием в pandas IPython и Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ipython

здравствуйте.

прошу, пожалуйста, подсказать. не выводится столбец.

при команде `df['Адрес покупателя']` выводит ошибку.

архив в нотбуком и самим csv файлом: 
http://dropmefiles.com/1M9qB

сам код:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\2\1.xlsx')
df[['Адрес покупателя']]
```

текст ошибки:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0994cd2849d3> in <module>()
----> 1 df[['Адрес покупателя']]

C:\Users\1\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   2054         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2055             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2056             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2057         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2058             return self._getitem_frame(key)

C:\Users\1\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2098             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2099         else:
-> 2100             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2101             return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2102 

C:\Users\1\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.pyc in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1229                 mask = check == -1
   1230                 if mask.any():
-> 1231                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1232 
   1233                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "[ '\\xd0\\x90\\xd0\\xb4\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x81 \\xd0\\xbf\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xba\\xd1\\x83\\xd0\\xbf\\xd0\\xb0\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbb\\xd1\\x8f'] not in index"
```

Comment: что показывает: `print(df.columns.tolist())`?

Comment: показывает:[u'\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0438', u'\u0421\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0430 \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430, $', u'\u0410\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441 \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044f', u'\u041a\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0433\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f \u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440\u0430']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_excel(fn, encoding='utf-8')

In [16]: df[[u'Адрес покупателя']]
Out[16]:
  Адрес покупателя
0         Проспект
```

PS обратите внимание на `u'...'`

```
 #                        ^
 #                        |
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @impregis, пожалуйста :)

Comment: а что такое u в команде : df[[u'Адрес покупателя']]

Comment: @impregis, так в Python 2.x обозначают строковые unicode literals